# Rhythmbox and metadata

Tags: rhythmbox, metadata

I was wondering whether there is way to make rhythmbox fetch or find metadata automatically online for all the songs in my library. Is such a task possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately no, Rhythmbox doesn't support fetching of metadata not even through plugins. But there are better alternatives available in Ubuntu repositories. I would suggest [EasyTAG](https://github.com/stsquad/easytag)

EasyTAG is an utility for viewing and editing tags for MP3, MP2, FLAC, Ogg
Vorbis, Speex, MP4/AAC, MusePack, Monkey's Audio and WavPack files. Its simple
and nice GTK2 interface makes tagging easier under GNU/Linux or Windows.

You can install it by running the following command in terminal.

`sudo apt-get install easytag`

or search for "easytag" in Software Center and install in from there.

Comment: It's a nice tool indeed, i guess i have found what to do for my summer vacation: rewrite my library metadata XD; Thanks for this advising me this app i was looking for something like this to if the auto mode wasn't available

Answer (score 2):

***[update]***

23.Dec 2017 (`rhythmbox 3.4.1`):

Rhythmbox is actually able to fetch metadata from online databases and write the metadata into (at least) mp3/ogg files and read metadata from mp3/ogg files.

It seems like it is not capable of reading/writing metadata from/to flac.

Comment: how to do that ?

Comment: @m3asmi If you import your music from a CD rhythmbox will do that automatically (if the album is in the online database). If you use mp3s you can manually edit the entries by rightclicking on the list entry, then select `Properties` (I think it is Properies, I use the German localization) and make the edits in the popup window.

Comment: This exlains how to **edit** the tags, but (apart from the album cover) I do not find any automatic fetching of tags there. How do I automatically fetch the information for an album?

Comment: @rubo77 When importing the music from a CD rhythmbox usually fetches the information. I don't think that there is another way to get the data using rhythmbox.